# How to trigger event using livewire edit form

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I would like to have two use cases in the same group of liveware components. For example, if the member does not select and when comes from a member and wants to be that member selected on the list for example to enter payments.
Here is my mount method:

```
public function mount($member = null)
{
    $this->payment = [
        'member_id' => $this->member,
        'amount' => 0,
        'payment_method' => null,
        'date' => null,
        'name' => null,
        'payer_name' => null,
    ];
    $this->member = $member;
}
public function render()
{
    $this->members =....

    return view('livewire.create-team-member-membership');
}
```

Select binder works OK, select right member:

```
<select class="block w-full mt-1 text-sm dark:text-gray-800 dark:border-gray-600 dark:bg-white
                form-select focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-purple dark:focus:shadow-outline-gray"
                name="member_id" id="member_id" wire:model="payment.member_id" wire:change="changedMember">
            <option value="">{{__('site.member_payments.select_member')}}</option>
            @foreach($members as $item)
                <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

but for some reason, changedMember didn't run well. That method emit event which shows other data for selected member:

```
$this->emit('memberChanged', ['member_id' => $this->payment['member_id']]);
```

but it fired when I manually select some other member. Is there any way I can call it for that already selected member?

I am trying to make some kind an edit form. When I open the payment form it loads all members from the database and when I click on some members it loads additional fields because the trigger changedMember() method emits an event that other components listen and all works well. But in the case when I want to add payment from member details, I like that member will be preselected and that works well with submitting member id on request, and liveware forms,.... but it didn't trigger changeMember event to other components know that needs to load the rest of data that they load on members select changed in the first scenario(need to change the value in a list of members to that would be triggered).

Comment: you might want to harness the ```updatedFoo, updatedBar``` methods livewire provides for each publicly declared property. Something like ```public function updatedChangedMember(){ ///do whatever you need to do here}```

Comment: Also read here for more details [Livewire lifecycle hooks](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: added updatedChangedMember but it never triggered.

Comment: Hey sorry for that. change the function name  like this ``` public function updatedPaymentMemberId()``` @mrakodol

Comment: the same, does not trigger nothing  :)

Comment: What do you see when you run this? ```public function updated($name,$value){ dd($name) }``` update the select after adding this method